# Learning the grep command and came across this. How does it work combined with tail?

Tags: bash, grep, tail

What would
`grep '&' input.txt | tail -4` give me? I am new to this and cannot figure out what happens using grep and tail together.

Comment: Unless this is part of a script, the question isn't really on-topic and should probably be asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Pipe doesn't change the commands.  Each does what they do separately.  All it does is  send the output of grep as the input to tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tail -4 when executed with a file would normally print the last four lines of the file

With:

```
grep '&' input.txt | tail -4
```

The tail command is being executed on the output of the grep command and so will print the last 4 lines of the output of grep.

If for example there are 50 occurrences of "&" in input.txt, only the last 4 will print.